# Issues geocoding with R and Google Maps

Tags: r, google-maps, geocoding, geocode

I've been running the following excellent code from...

https://www.shanelynn.ie/massive-geocoding-with-r-and-google-maps/

It works like a dream, but... randomly it stops mid process and throws an error. This happens at different points using the same data set. I've taken one of the addresses that threw an error and manually ran it through the code and it worked fine?? I think it might be a server or time out issue that is causing this. Has anyone else used this code and have you had similar issues? Did you find a solution?

The error always looks something like...

```
contacting http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NICHOLS,%20ACT,%202613,%20AUSTRALIA&sensor=false...Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NICHOLS,%20ACT,%202613,%20AUSTRALIA&sensor=false
Error in geo_reply$status : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(connect, warn = FALSE) :
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NICHOLS,%20ACT,%202613,%20AUSTRALIA&sensor=false': HTTP status was '500 Internal Server Error'
2: In geocode(address, output = "all", messaging = TRUE, override_limit = TRUE) :
geocoding failed for "NICHOLS, ACT, 2613, AUSTRALIA".
if accompanied by 500 Internal Server Error with using dsk, try google.
```

My address is in a data table like (around 2,000 records)...

| MAIL_STATE | MAIL_SUBBURB | MAIL_POSTCODE |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------------- |
| ACT        | NICHOLLS     | 2613          |

addresses is created by using the following code...

```
addresses = paste0(data$MAIL_SUBURB,", ",data$MAIL_STATE,", ",data$MAIL_POSTCODE,", AUSTRALIA", sep = "")
```

The full code which utilises addressses is below...

```
#define a function that will process googles server responses for us.
getGeoDetails <- function(address){   
#use the gecode function to query google servers
geo_reply = geocode(address, output='all', messaging=TRUE, override_limit=TRUE)
#now extract the bits that we need from the returned list
answer <- data.frame(lat=NA, long=NA, accuracy=NA, formatted_address=NA, address_type=NA, status=NA)
answer$status <- geo_reply$status

#if we are over the query limit - want to pause for an hour
while(geo_reply$status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"){
print("OVER QUERY LIMIT - Pausing for 24 hours at:") 
time <- Sys.time()
print(as.character(time))
Sys.sleep(60*60*24)
geo_reply = geocode(address, output='all', messaging=TRUE, override_limit=TRUE)
answer$status <- geo_reply$status
}

#return Na's if we didn't get a match:
if (geo_reply$status != "OK"){
return(answer)
}   
#else, extract what we need from the Google server reply into a dataframe:
answer$lat <- geo_reply$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
answer$long <- geo_reply$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng   
if (length(geo_reply$results[[1]]$types) > 0){
answer$accuracy <- geo_reply$results[[1]]$types[[1]]
}
answer$address_type <- paste(geo_reply$results[[1]]$types, collapse=',')
answer$formatted_address <- geo_reply$results[[1]]$formatted_address

return(answer)
}

#initialise a dataframe to hold the results
geocoded <- data.frame()
# find out where to start in the address list (if the script was interrupted before):
startindex <- 1
#if a temp file exists - load it up and count the rows!
tempfilename <- paste0(infile, '_temp_geocoded.rds')
if (file.exists(tempfilename)){
print("Found temp file - resuming from index:")
geocoded <- readRDS(tempfilename)
startindex <- nrow(geocoded)
print(startindex)
}



# Start the geocoding process - address by address. geocode() function takes care of query speed limit.
for (ii in seq(startindex, length(addresses))){
print(paste("Working on index", ii, "of", length(addresses)))
#query the google geocoder - this will pause here if we are over the limit.
result = getGeoDetails(addresses[ii]) 
print(result$status)     
result$index <- ii
#append the answer to the results file.
geocoded <- rbind(geocoded, result)
#save temporary results as we are going along
saveRDS(geocoded, tempfilename)
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your code. i just tried http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NICHOLS,%20ACT,%202613,%20AUSTRALIA&sensor=false and this works well. I suspect restriction on google servers (limited number calls per second/minute)

Comment: @EricLecoutre, thanks. As I said, this code works well ...up to the point where it fails! And there is no pattern to the failure. It is random. Is there a way you can build into the code a throttle to slow down the number of requests per minute, OR is it more likely to be a network issue delaying receipt of the results?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like this version.

```
# Geocoding a csv column of "addresses" in R

#load ggmap
library(ggmap)

# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity of your approach. That said, the data I have to work with is pretty shabby and there are a number of incorrect addresses in it. One of these forced the loop to fail as follows...

.Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CRAIGIE,%20ACT,%202632,%20AUSTRALIA&sensor=false
    Error in `[.data.frame`(result, 3) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "CRAIGIE, ACT, 2632, AUSTRALIA"

I'd need to work out a way to deal with these errors to make it viable.

Comment: Well, I'm not an R expert by any means, but I guess you're going to have to handle the errors somehow, and clean up the data set as well.  Maybe this will help, at least for setting up some Try...Catch blocks..  https://www.r-bloggers.com/error-handling-in-r/

Comment: Seems OK...

    for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) 
    {
      # Print("Working...")
      result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
      if(is.na(result$lon)) {
      origAddress$lon[i] <- 99
      origAddress$lat[i] <- 99
      origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- "Error"
      } else {
      result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
      origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
      origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
      origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
      }
    }

Comment: The above acted as expected, recording lat, long and address; and recording errors where the address couldn't be found. It then returned NA for one address and then beyond this it recorded Errors for about 100 addresses ...before carying on as expected! The 100 addresses were valid for geocoding ie, they exist in Google's DB. Not sure where to go from here!

Comment: Have decided to try a different route using the original code but using Suburb and Post Code data retrieved from a Government based public source. This works fine as all of the addresses are valid. I'm then going to reference this directly locally, rather than making an API call to Google; which seems to fall over if too many consecutive addresses are incorrect. Having the data availble locally should (I hope) allow me to work with my less than perfect source data more effectively.